# Liferay 6.2 GA4 portal-log4j-ext.xml reload interval?

Tags: log4j, liferay, liferay-6

Does anybody know what Liferay's reload interval is for portal-log4j-ext.xml and if there is none how to configure one? My goal is to change the log level for certain packages from e.g. WARN to DEBUG without bouncing the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a reload interval. But you can go to Control Panel / Server Administration. There's a tab containing Log levels and you can change the existing ones or introduce new ones. They'll be active immediately.

Caution: Upon restarting the server, the settings are lost (by design) and you'll start over with the file-based logging configuration. But as restarting is not an option for you, this should solve your problem. Of course you're still free to edit the file so that your settings will become active by default on restart.

Comment: Thanks Olaf. I find it interesting, since log4j is solely design to be file based that liferay decided to put a UI on top of it and not to support the file features such as automatic reload.

I wonder if log4j's configureAndWatch can be invoked somehow, perhaps in a startup hook to reload portal-log4j-ext.xml

Comment: Well, a web application might be just a war file, still zipped. There might not even be an accessible log4j configuration file on disk. Thus the UI makes sense IMHO

Comment: that being said, supporting all available options would also be nice. Note that I didn't say that Liferay doesn't support reloading. I'm just not aware of it...